# Maven plugin dependency - using the source plugin in all my poms

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-source-plugin

I would like to configure the use of the maven source plugin for all our projects. The way our projects are currently configured we have a parent pom that is inherited by all the projects. So, in order for all projects to use the maven source plugin, I did the following:

1. Defined the maven source plugin under `build -> plugin management` in the parent pom

   > ```
   >             <plugin>
   >             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   >             <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
   >             <version>2.2.1</version>
   >             <executions>
   >                 <execution>
   >                     <id>attach-sources</id>
   >                     <goals>
   >                         <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
   >                     </goals>
   >                 </execution>
   >             </executions>
   >         </plugin>
   > ```
2. In my project pom (the child pom), I have included the source plugin under `build -> plugins`

> ```
>         <plugin>
>             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>             <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
>         </plugin>
> ```

Could someone please tell me if this is the best way to configure this? Is there any way you can avoid specifying the source plugin in the child pom?

Comment: Yes, you can avoid specifying the source plugin in each of the child projects. For this you need to put it to `build -> plugins` section of parent pom, not `build -> pluginManagement`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the best way.

To avoid having to add the plugin declaration in the child pom you could add it to the build/plugins section in the parent. The problem with that however is that EVERY child gets that invocation added even if it does not make sense if e.g. the child is a pom or ear packaging. You should therefore not do this..

Comment: I didn't add it to my comment, but I fully agree with your idea.

Comment: Thanks, I too agree with the suggestion of not using it blindly with every child project.

Comment: @ManfredMoser @AndrewLogvinov Is it possible to do a *conditional* `<execution>` in the parent POM, so that it is only done for `<packaging>jar</packaging>` child projects?  Then one *could* just put it in the parent's `<build>` `<plugins>` section...

Comment: @MarnixKlooster I don't think there's a more or less easy way to do this. I guess easier way would be to set execution for all child modules and skip it where not needed (property `source.skip`).